# Automatically add OneDrive and Team sites from On-Premise Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, onedrive-for-business, team-sites, sync, libraries

I was reading this tutorial about how to connect new users to sharepoint team sites and onedrive folder automatically via GPO settings.

https://www.blackforce.co.uk/2019/06/07/automatically-sync-microsoft-sharepoint-team-site-libraries-now-live

But all the websites mention, in the option "Configure team site libraries to sync automatically" I need the parameter - very long string that I need to enter in the Value field. This can be retrieved when I click on Sync button on link Copy library ID which is available on Sharepoint Online, but not on Sharepoint 2019 libraries.

How can I get this parameter from my local sharepoint installation and configure the libraries via GPO from local sharepoint? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid not.

Quoting the configurate documentation: "This feature is not enabled for on-premises SharePoint sites."

Reference: [Use Group Policy to control OneDrive sync settings.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-group-policy#configure-team-site-libraries-to-sync-automatically)